# Detecting if a TeamCity backup was successful using the API

Tags: rest, powershell, backup, teamcity

I am writing a PowerShell script to run a TeamCity data backup using the REST API and while I can start a backup and detect when it has finished, I cannot find an API call that tells me whether the backup succeeded or not. Am I missing something or is this information just not available via the API?

Comment: If I need to provide more information here, can someone please tell me what that information is please.

Answer (score 0):

The API is async , so in my backup script I loop to see when it finishes.

```
#start backup
$StartBackupUrl = "http://$TeamCityHostAndPort/httpAuth/app/rest/server/backup?includeConfigs=true&includeDatabase=true&includeBuildLogs=true&fileName=TeamCity_Backup_"
$filename = Invoke-RestMethod -WebSession $TeamCitySession -Method Post -Uri $StartBackupUrl

Write-Host "TeamCity backup on $filename started"

# wait for backup to finish
$GetBackupStatusUrl = "http://$TeamCityHostAndPort/httpAuth/app/rest/server/backup"
do {
    $backupStatus = Invoke-RestMethod -WebSession $TeamCitySession -Method Get -Uri $GetBackupStatusUrl
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
} while ($backupStatus -eq 'Running')
```

Comment: Thanks, as I said in the question, I can detect when it finishes, using the same principle that you are but what I cannot find is a way to detect whether it succeeded or not as it simply goes back to an "idle" state.

Comment: Pardon. You are right, there is no documented way to get this info. You can screen-scrap and guess if the file name generated matches your request... but it is really ugly.